# Fejer-Riesz Theorem for analytic polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, trigonometric-series

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z| <1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z: |z|=1\}$. Suppose $D$ and $E$ are polynomials of degree atmost $n$ with complex coefficients such that

1. $|E(z)| \leq |D(z)|$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$
2. $D(z) \ne 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.
3. $E(z)=z^n\overline{E(1/\overline{z})}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
4. $z \mapsto |E(z)|^2-|D(z)|^2$ for $z \in \mathbb{T}$ has only finitely many zeros.

Prove that there exists a polynomial $A$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|A(z)|^2=|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

My attempt: First note that for $z \in \mathbb{T}$, the function $Q(z)=|E(z)|^2-|D(z)|^2$ is a trigonometric polynomial. By given hypothesis, $Q(z) \geq 0$ on $\mathbb{T}$ and $Q$ is not identically zero. By Fejer-Riesz Theorem, there exists a polynomial $A$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|A(z)|^2=|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$.

How to proceed further? Any hints/ suggestions.

Comment: this doesn't work with counterxample as before with a scaling; take $E(z)=(2z-1)(z-2), D(z)=2(z-2)^2$ so $2|E(z)|=|D(z)|$ on the unit circle, hence $2|A(z)|=\sqrt 3 |D(z)|$ on the unit circle, but then $|2A/(\sqrt 3 D)|$ is analytic on the (closed) unit disc and of modulus one on the unit circle, hence it's a finite Blaschke product and the nonvanishing condition on $A$ implies it's constant which leads to a contradiction as before as inside the unit disc we have $2|E(z)| < |D(z)|$